# Update API data on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I am using this little library https://github.com/frmlnd/frmlnd-current to add cart price with other currency.

Here is how we display price value in other currency:

`<span class="crrnt-currency inline" data-crrnt-base="USD" data-crrnt-currencies="GBP">$100</span>`

All works good!

But then we are trying to display different price options after the page loaded via onlick event, but the additional currency rate is not firing since the change happens later in the DOM.

Click code

```
$('.payment-option').on('click', 'label', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.order-summary .inner p').html($(this).data('product'));
    $('.order-summary .total .right').html('<span class="crrnt-currency click" data-crrnt-base="USD" data-crrnt-currencies="GBP">' + $(this).data('amount') + '</span>');

});
```

What needs be done?

Here i have put in a demo sample of the issue https://jsfiddle.net/mironomadic/hw1cbz0t/1/

Notice on first load we are getting the currency exchange value in GBP as expected, but once we click on price 1 or 2 currency value in GBP does not fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change these codes to

```
$('.payment-option').on('click', 'label', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.order-summary .inner p').html($(this).data('product'));
    $('.order-summary .total .right em').empty().html(`<span class="crrnt-currency inline" data-crrnt-base="USD" data-crrnt-currencies="GBP">${$(this).data("amount")} </span>`);
$('.crrnt-currency').current({
        api: 'https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=6851e9a79b90414b8a35d3776790f60d'
    });
});
```

The important is call the `current api` again.

Answer (score 1):

It works if you call the API again after updating the element:

```
const updateCurrencies = () => {
    $('.crrnt-currency').current({
      api: 'https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=6851e9a79b90414b8a35d3776790f60d'
    });
};
$('.payment-option').on('click', 'label', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.order-summary .inner p').html($(this).data('product'));
  const newE = '<span class="crrnt-currency inline" data-crrnt-base="USD" data-crrnt-currencies="GBP">' + $(this).data('amount') + '</span>'
    $('.order-summary .total .right').html(newE);

    updateCurrencies();
});


jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    updateCurrencies();
});
```